# Minimising the sum of array columns in Matlab

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, optimization, statistics

I have a large array (approx 250,000 x 10). Each row contains 1s or -1s. E.g:

```
data(1, :) = [1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1];
```

I need to select sets of n rows, such that the **mean of the absolute sums of the columns** is minimized (as close to zero as possible). So, in this toy example, where n=2:

```
[ 1  1  1  1]
[-1 -1 -1 -1]
[-1  1 -1  1]
```

I would select rows 1 and 2, as they sum to [0 0 0 0] (mean 0), which is the minimum possible when n=2.

---

I tried the method suggested below (of finding complementary pairs), but for my dataset, this can only form a balanced subset of 23k rows. So, I need an approximation which generates a subset of size n rows, but with the minimum means of absolute sums of the columns.

The best approach I have found so far is as follows: pick a starting subset, iteratively add each row from the remainder to the base, and keep it if it improves the mean of the absolute sums of the columns. This is very crude and I am sure there are better ways. It is also prone to getting stuck at false minima, so a contingency needs to be added:

```
shuffle = randperm(size(data));
data_shuffled = data(shuffle, :);

base = data_shuffled(1:30000, :);
pool = data_shuffled(30001:end, :);

best_mean = mean(abs(sum(base, 1)));
best_matrix = base;
n = 100000;

for k = 1:20

    for i = 1:size(pool, 1)
        temp = pool (i, :);

        if(~isnan(temp(1)))
            temp_sum = sum(temp, 1);
            new_sum = temp_sum + sum(best, 1);
            temp_mean = mean(abs(new_sum));

            if(temp_mean < best_mean)
                best_mean = temp_mean;
                best_matrix = vertcat(best_matrix, temp);
                pool(i, :) = NaN(1, 10);            
            end
        end
    end

    if(size(best_matrix, 1) > n)
        return
    end

end
```

This achieves a mean of the absolute sums of the columns of ~17,000, which is not too bad. Repeating with different seeds will probably improve it a bit.

Ideally, rather than just adding the new element to the end of best_matrix, I would **swap it** with some element, so as to achieve the best improvement.

**Update: I don't want to give out specific details of the dataset because all solutions should be applicable to any matrices in the specified format.**

***Thank you to everyone that contributed!***

Comment: Is Looping through all possible combinations of rows an Option or do you Need the program to be fast?

Comment: It is acceptable if the program takes a few hours. n will be in the region of 100k though. I was wondering if there was a dynamic programming solution?

Comment: Wow, we are talking C(250k,100k), which is HUGE, so no option in brute force. But there are only 2^10 (1024) possible rows, so depending on the distribution on your data, any combination of 1s and -1s should appear around 250 times. Maybe you can try to pair rows with it's opposite and gather as many pairs as you can, hopefully 50k pairs.

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure you want to minimise the *absolute value of* something, since otherwise you should pick rows with as many (and as large) negative values as possible.  Second, are you sure you want to minimise the *mean* sum?  That means that a set of rows having sum [1000 -1000 1000 -1000] (with mean 0) is better than a set of rows having sum [0 0 1 0].

Comment: @NoelSegura: I think you nailed it. It's more than 2^10 iterations because now you can choose the same row multiple times, but it is small enough to brute force.

Comment: Thanks to @j_random_hacker, I do need to find the absolute sum (question updated).

Comment: I am trying @NoelSegura idea, but it looks like very few of the possible complements exist, so forming a large enough the balanced dataset using pairs might not work.

Comment: Yeah, my idea depends heavily on the distribution of your data. If you have at least 100 of every possible row, then you are done, but if you have a lot of one kind and none of others, then you might need a different strategy. Maybe you can plot an histogram of your data vs the possible rows, so we can see the distribution of the data and help you better.

Comment: Is a set of rows with sums [1000 -1000 1000 -1000] better than a set of rows with sums [0 0 1 0]?  Because your current criterion says that it is.

Comment: No. I am taking the mean of the absolute column sums: mean(abs(sum(data)), where data is the whole matrix (so, sum(data) gives the column sums). Using your examples, mean(abs([1000 -1000 1000 -1000]) = 1000. mean(abs([0 0 1 0]) = 0.25. So, the latter is better.

Comment: Have you considered working on a sort of accumulator space? Like, let's call [-1,-1,-1,-1] id=0,[-1,-1,-1,1] id=1....[1,1,1,-1] id=14,[1,1,1,1] id=15. Then run once over your data doing acumm(id)+=1. At the end you'll have a more manageable data. Also the pairs would be of the form (k, 1023-k), so you can get them very quickly and work only on the unpairable data

Comment: In that case, your criterion is equivalent to minimising the *sum* of the absolute values of the column sums (since the mean that you're talking about is just that same sum, divided by the number of columns -- which of course is a constant).  You've reworded the question to make it clear that taking the mean comes after taking the absolute values, and that's good, but I'd suggest writing "sum" instead of "mean" to avoid making the problem seem more complicated than it is.

Comment: I think I might have a different approach to the pairs and quadruplets I posted below, but I would like to know the result of `sum(data)` of your data to see if it makes sense

Comment: I just edited my answer with what I worked on over the weekend, hopefully it will help

Comment: @ChrisParry you can simplify the problem by pre-computing the sum of each row in a seperate matrix, to minimize the number of possible combinations you have to check.

Comment: If you treat each row as a bit string of 0's or 1's, you can evaluate hamming distance between any two very efficiently. You want to choose rows in pairs such that each pair has the maximum hamming distance. This is effectively a greedy approach - you are trying to minimize the sum over a 1-step horizon and are repeating that each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other had stated an optimal solution might be impossible, so I'll focus on specific cases.

First I assume independence of the distributions of each columns.

Then I work on accumulator space to reduce the size of data and speed the code.

I do it by taking each `-1` as `0` and considering each row as a number, and add 1 to avoid working with 0 as an index, such as:

```
data(1,:)=[-1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1] -> '0101010101' -> 341 -> 342
```

With this we can accumulate the data as:

```
function accum=mat2accum(data)

[~,n]=size(data);
indexes=bin2dec(num2str((data+1)/2))+1;
accum=accumarray(indexes,1,[2^n 1]);
```

First case I consider is when the sum of each column is a small number compared to the size of the data, this means that there is a similar amount of 1's and -1's in all columns.

```
sum(data) << size(data)
```

For this case you can find all the pairs that cancel each other like:

```
data(1,:)=[-1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1] -> '0101010101' -> 341 -> 342
data(2,:)=[1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1] -> '1010101010' -> 682 -> 683
```

And we know that each pair will be in the mirrored position in the accumulator index, so we can get all possible pairs with:

```
function [accumpairs, accumleft]=getpairs(accum)

accumpairs=min([accum,accum(end:-1:1)],[],2);
accumleft=accum-accumpairs;
```

With random generated data I was able to get >100k pairs in a set of 250k rows, and a subset of pairs will have a sum equal to zero in each column. So if 1's and -1's are equally distributed, this might be enough.

---

Second case I considered was when the sum of each column is far from zero, meaning that there is a big disproportion between 1's and -1's.

```
abs(sum(data)) >> 0
```

By inverting each column where the sum is negative, which would not affect the data since at the end it is possible to invert those columns again. Its is possible to force the disproportion to be more 1's than -1's. And by extracting first the possible pairs of this data, the disproportion is even more pronounced.

With the data prepared as such, it is possible to treat the problem as to minimize the number of 1's in the set required. For this first we randomize the possible indexes, then we calculate and sort the Hamming weight (number of 1's in the binary representation) of each index, and then gather the data with the smallest Hamming weight possible.

```
function [accumlast,accumleft]=resto(accum,m)

[N,~]=size(accum);
columns=log2(N);
indexes=randperm(N)'; %'
[~,I]=sort(sum((double(dec2bin(indexes-1,columns))-48),2));
accumlast=zeros(N,1);

for k=indexes(I)' %'
    accumlast(k)=accum(k);
    if sum(accumlast)>=m
        break
    end
end

accumleft=accum-accumlast;
```

With randomly generated data where there were around 2 times more 1's than -1's, and the sum of each column was around 80k, I can find a subset of 100k data with sum of around 5k in each column.

---

Third case, is when some columns sum are close to zero and some aren't. In this case you separate the columns into the ones with big sum and the ones with small sum, then sort the data by the hamming weight of the big sum columns, and get the pairs of the small sum columns inside each of the big columns index. This will create a matrix with the number of possible pairs, the number of unpairbale rows, and the sum of the unpairable rows of the small columns, for each index of the big sum columns.

Now you can use that information to keep a running sum and see which indexes of the big sum columns to add to your subset, and also if it's worth to add the parable or the unpairable data in each case.

```
function [accumout,accumleft]=getseparated(accum, bigcol, smallcol, m)

data=accum2mat(accum);

'indexing'
bigindex=bin2dec(num2str((data(:,bigcol)+1)/2))+1;
[~,bn]=size(bigcol);
[~,sn]=size(smallcol);

'Hamming weight'
b_ind=randperm(2^bn)'; %'
[~,I]=sort(sum((double(dec2bin(b_ind-1,bn))-48),2));

temp=zeros(2^bn,4+sn);

w=waitbar(0,'Processing');
for k=1:2^bn;
    small_data=data(bigindex==b_ind(I(k)),smallcol);
    if small_data
        small_accum=mat2accum(small_data);
        [small_accumpairs, small_accum]=getpairs(small_accum);
        n_pairs=sum(small_accumpairs);
        n_non_pairs=sum(small_accum);
        sum_non_pairs=sum(accum2mat(small_accum));
    else
        n_pairs=0;
        n_non_pairs=0;
        sum_non_pairs=zeros(1,sn);
    end
    ham_weight=sum((double(dec2bin(b_ind(I(k))-1,bn))-48),2);
    temp(k,:)=[b_ind(I(k)) n_pairs n_non_pairs ham_weight sum_non_pairs];
    waitbar(k/2^bn);
end

close(w)

pair_ind=1;
nonpair_ind=1;
runningsum=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
temp2=zeros(2^bn,2);

while sum(sum(temp2))<=m
     if pair_ind<=2^bn
         pairsum=[(((double(dec2bin((temp(pair_ind,1)-1),bn))-48)*2)-1)*temp(pair_ind,2) zeros(1,sn)];
     end
     if nonpair_ind<=2^bn
         nonpairsum=[(((double(dec2bin((temp(nonpair_ind,1)-1),bn))-48)*2)-1)*temp(nonpair_ind,3) temp(nonpair_ind,5:5+sn-1)];
     end
     if nonpair_ind==(2^bn)+1
         temp2(pair_ind,1)=temp(pair_ind,2);
         runningsum=runningsum+pairsum;
         pair_ind=pair_ind+1;
     elseif pair_ind==(2^bn)+1
         temp2(nonpair_ind,2)=temp(nonpair_ind,3);
         runningsum=runningsum+nonpairsum;
         nonpair_ind=nonpair_ind+1;
     elseif sum(abs(runningsum+pairsum))<=sum(abs(runningsum+nonpairsum))
         temp2(pair_ind,1)=temp(pair_ind,2);
         runningsum=runningsum+pairsum;
         pair_ind=pair_ind+1;
     elseif sum(abs(runningsum+pairsum))>sum(abs(runningsum+nonpairsum))
         temp2(nonpair_ind,2)=temp(nonpair_ind,3);
         runningsum=runningsum+nonpairsum;
         nonpair_ind=nonpair_ind+1;
     end
end

accumout=zeros(2^(bn+sn),1);

for k=1:2^bn
    if temp2(k,:)
        small_data=data(bigindex==temp(k,1),smallcol);
        if small_data
            small_accum=mat2accum(small_data);
            [small_accumpairs, small_accum]=getpairs(small_accum);
            pairs=accum2mat(small_accumpairs);
            non_pairs=accum2mat(small_accum);
        else
            pairs=zeros(1,sn);
            non_pairs=zeros(1,sn);
        end
        if temp2(k,1)
            datatemp=zeros(temp2(k,1),sn+bn);
            datatemp(:,bigcol)=((double(dec2bin(ones(temp2(k,1),1)*(temp(k,1)-1),bn))-48)*2)-1;
            datatemp(:,smallcol)=pairs;
            accumout=accumout+mat2accum(datatemp);
        end
        if temp2(k,2)
            datatemp=zeros(temp2(k,2),sn+bn);
            datatemp(:,bigcol)=((double(dec2bin(ones(temp2(k,2),1)*(temp(k,1)-1),bn))-48)*2)-1;
            datatemp(:,smallcol)=non_pairs;
            accumout=accumout+mat2accum(datatemp);
        end
    end
end

accumleft=accum-accumout;
```

With data composed of 5 columns of the first case and 5 columns of the second case, it was possible to constructt a set of 100k rows with <1k of sum in the small sum columns and between 10k and 30k in the big ones.

It's worth noting that the size of data, size of the required subset, and distributtion of 1's and -1's, will have a great effect in the performance of this algorithmms.

Answer (score 3):

What about the following approach. With 10 columns only having +1 and -1 values, there are only 1024 different rows possible. So our data is now:

1. a 1024 x 10 matrix `a(i,j)` with -1 and +1 coefficients. This matrix has all different possible (unique) rows.
2. a vector `v(i)` with how many times we saw row i.

Now we can write a simple Mixed Integer Programming problem as follows:

[image]

Notes:

- We only have 1024 integer variables
- We set an upper bound on x(i) that indicates how many times a row can be selected
- We use a so-called variable splitting technique to model the absolute values and keep the model linear
- Minimizing the mean is the same as minimizing the sum (the difference is a constant factor)
- The line about optcr tells the MIP solver to find proven global optimal solutions
- A good MIP solver should be able to find solutions very quickly. I tested with some random data using 250k rows and N=100. 
  I actually believe this is an easy problem.
- To reiterate: this method delivers proven global optimal solutions.
- Some more details can be found [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/mip-vs-matlab.html).

Comment: Nice... Is there a MATLAB Toolbox for MIP?

Comment: Yes. The [optimization toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/linear-programming-and-mixed-integer-linear-programming.html) has a MIP solver. More advanced solvers: Cplex and Gurobi also have Matlab APIs.

Comment: Is there a free solver (High Quality) for MATLAB? Thank You.

Comment: YALMIP is a nice toolbox and it supports CBC (a really good open source MIP solver). Resuts with CBC on the above model are [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/mip-vs-matlab.html).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about that tool.

Answer (score 1):

This problem, sadly, falls outside the scope of regular (continuous) optimization. Your problem, which can be parameterized as follows:

```
min_{S∈S_n} Σ_{j∈S}|Σ_i data_ji|
```

Where `S_n` is the set of n-elements combinations of indices `j∈{0,...,250000}`, can also be rewritten as a very similar regular Quadratic Integer Programming problem in `x`:

```
min_x x'* data *data' *x
0<=x<=1 and x*1=n
```

Where `data` is your 250000*10 matrix and `x` is the 250000*1 vector of combinations we're looking for. (Now we optimize the sum of squares instead of the sum of absolute values... )

This problem is **proven** to be [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Proof_of_NP-hardness), which means to find the global minimizer, you must go through all possible combinations of n draws in 250000 possibilities, which is equal to the binomial coefficient (250000 n), which is equal to `250000!/(n!*(250000-n)!)`...

So good luck... ;)

**EDIT**

If you're going to solve this heuristically, since I suppose you're going to need a solution, use the heuristics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Heuristic_methods) instead of your approach.

Comment: I don't think the statement 'NP-hard => you must go through all combinations' is correct. E.g. MIP solvers don't visit all possible solutions.

Comment: Yes I wrote that quickly, but integer programming is NP hard by reduction to the vertex cover problem. But you're right there appears to be smaller big-o solving complexities than exhaustive searches there... will edit answer when time!

Answer (score 0):

Since your responses seemed to indicate you were interested in finding larger sequences (larger n) the code below attempts to find the largest n allowing up to 10% of the rows (i.e. 25,000) to be removed. That is the code minimizes `sum( abs( sum( data, 1)))` of the full data set by removing the best row from the set up to 25,000 times.  This should be the same as minimizing the mean (your stated problem).  The code uses indices in the range `[1, 1024]` for efficiency until the final output is produced in the last step.   The order variable is set to 10 (your stated problem) corresponding to `2^10 = 1024` possible row vectors.   An index for a given row vector, for example  `[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1]`, is found by setting all -1 values to 0 and taking the binary representation.  So in this example the index to the row vector is `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] = 1`.  (Note the index 1 is actually converted to 2 since MATLAB does not allow an index of 0.)

I have tested this for a uniform random distribution (an easy case) and it generally converges to a true min (i.e. `sum( abs( sum( data, 1))) = 0`) after removing ~1000 rows. [Click here to run the example code below for the uniform random case on AlgorithmHub](https://cloud.algorithmhub.com/s/ebdb296e-9531-47f9-932a-fcae1a58ac4e/app).  A new random set will be chosen each time you run and will generally take about 30 seconds to complete on that infrastructure.

[Click here to upload a csv file of your data set and run the example code on AlgorithmHub](https://cloud.algorithmhub.com/s/a699f5df-d149-4a2c-a01c-ee3e1eea91db/app). An link to output.cvs will allow you to download the results. The code should be easily modified to support your method of adding new rows if you want to obtain a specific n.  Using the index idea should with the corresponding look-up table (lut) will help keep this efficient. Otherwise if you want a specific large n you can keep removing rows even when the sum is 0 (minimum).

```
% Generate data set as vector of length order with elements in set {1,-1}.
tic();
rows  = 250000;
order = 10;
rowFraction = 0.1;
maxRowsToRemove = rows * rowFraction;
data  = rand( rows, order);
data( data >= 0.5) =  1;
data( data <  0.5) = -1;

% Convert data to an index to one of 2^order vectors of 1 or -1.
% We set the -1 values to 0 and get the binary representation of the
% vector of binary values.
a = data;
a( a==-1)=0;
ndx    = zeros(1,length(a));
ndx(:) = a(:,1)*2^9+a(:,2)*2^8+a(:,3)*2^7+a(:,4)*2^6+a(:,5)*2^5+...
         a(:,6)*2^4+a(:,7)*2^3+a(:,8)*2^2+a(:,9)*2+a(:,10) + 1;

% Determine how many of each index we have in data pool.
bins        = zeros( 1, 2^order);
binsRemoved = zeros( 1, 2^order);
for ii = 1:length( ndx)
    bins( ndx(ii)) = bins( ndx(ii)) + 1;
end

colSum = sum(data,1);
sumOfColSum = sum(abs(colSum));
absSum = sumOfColSum;
lut = genLutForNdx( order);

nRemoved = 0;
curSum = colSum;
for ii = 1:maxRowsToRemove
    if ( absSum == 0)
        disp( sprintf( '\nminimum solution found'));
        break;
    end
    ndxR = findNdxToRemove( curSum, bins, lut);
    if ndxR > 0
        bins( ndxR) = bins( ndxR) - 1;
        binsRemoved( ndxR) = binsRemoved( ndxR) + 1;
        curSum = curSum - lut( ndxR, :);
        nRemoved = nRemoved + 1;
        absSum = sum( abs( curSum));
    else
        disp( sprintf( '\nearly termination'));
        break;
    end
end

stat1 = sprintf( ...
    'stats-L1: original sum = %d, final sum = %d, num rows removed = %d',...
    sumOfColSum, absSum, nRemoved);
stat2 = sprintf( ...
    'stats-L2: iter = %d, run time = %.2f sec\n', ii, toc());
disp( stat1);
disp( stat2);

% Show list of indicies removed along with the number of each removed.
binRndx   = find( binsRemoved != 0);
ndxRemovedHist = [binRndx', binsRemoved(binRndx(:))'];
disp( sprintf( '%s\t%s', 'INDEX', 'NUM_REMOVED'));
for ii = 1: length( ndxRemovedHist)
    disp( sprintf( '%d\t%d', ndxRemovedHist(ii,1), ndxRemovedHist(ii,2)));
end

% Generate the modified data array from the list of removed elements.
modData = data;
lr      = [];
for ii = 1: length( ndxRemovedHist)
    sr = find( ndx==ndxRemovedHist(ii,1));
    lr = [lr, sr(1:ndxRemovedHist(ii,2))];
end
modData( lr, :) = [];
disp( sprintf( 'modified data array in variable "modData"'));

% ****************************************************
% Generate data set as vector of length order with elements in set {1,-1}.
tic();
rows  = 250000;
order = 10;
rowFraction = 0.1;
maxRowsToRemove = rows * rowFraction;
data  = rand( rows, order);
data( data >= 0.5) =  1;
data( data <  0.5) = -1;

% Convert data to an index to one of 2^order vectors of 1 or -1.
% We set the -1 values to 0 and get the binary representation of the
% vector of binary values.
a = data;
a( a==-1)=0;
ndx    = zeros(1,length(a));
ndx(:) = a(:,1)*2^9+a(:,2)*2^8+a(:,3)*2^7+a(:,4)*2^6+a(:,5)*2^5+...
         a(:,6)*2^4+a(:,7)*2^3+a(:,8)*2^2+a(:,9)*2+a(:,10) + 1;

% Determine how many of each index we have in data pool.
bins        = zeros( 1, 2^order);
binsRemoved = zeros( 1, 2^order);
for ii = 1:length( ndx)
    bins( ndx(ii)) = bins( ndx(ii)) + 1;
end

colSum = sum(data,1);
sumOfColSum = sum(abs(colSum));
absSum = sumOfColSum;
lut = genLutForNdx( order);

nRemoved = 0;
curSum = colSum;
for ii = 1:maxRowsToRemove
    if ( absSum == 0)
        disp( sprintf( '\nminimum solution found'));
        break;
    end
    ndxR = findNdxToRemove( curSum, bins, lut);
    if ndxR > 0
        bins( ndxR) = bins( ndxR) - 1;
        binsRemoved( ndxR) = binsRemoved( ndxR) + 1;
        curSum = curSum - lut( ndxR, :);
        nRemoved = nRemoved + 1;
        absSum = sum( abs( curSum));
    else
        disp( sprintf( '\nearly termination'));
        break;
    end
end

stat1 = sprintf( ...
    'stats-L1: original sum = %d, final sum = %d, num rows removed = %d',...
    sumOfColSum, absSum, nRemoved);
stat2 = sprintf( ...
    'stats-L2: iter = %d, run time = %.2f sec\n', ii, toc());
disp( stat1);
disp( stat2);

% Show list of indicies removed along with the number of each removed.
binRndx   = find( binsRemoved != 0);
ndxRemovedHist = [binRndx', binsRemoved(binRndx(:))'];
disp( sprintf( '%s\t%s', 'INDEX', 'NUM_REMOVED'));
for ii = 1: length( ndxRemovedHist)
    disp( sprintf( '%d\t%d', ndxRemovedHist(ii,1), ndxRemovedHist(ii,2)));
end

% Generate the modified data array from the list of removed elements.
modData = data;
lr      = [];
for ii = 1: length( ndxRemovedHist)
    sr = find( ndx==ndxRemovedHist(ii,1));
    lr = [lr, sr(1:ndxRemovedHist(ii,2))];
end
modData( lr, :) = [];
disp( sprintf( 'modified data array in variable "modData"'));

% ****************************************************
function ndx = findNdxToRemove( curSum, bins, lut)

% See if ideal index to remove exists in current bin set.  We look at the
% sign of each element of the current sum to determine index to remove  
aa = zeros( size( curSum));
if (isempty( find( curSum == 0)))

    aa( curSum <  0) = 0;
    aa( curSum >  0) = 1;
    ndx  = aa(1)*2^9+aa(2)*2^8+aa(3)*2^7+aa(4)*2^6+aa(5)*2^5+...
           aa(6)*2^4+aa(7)*2^3+aa(8)*2^2+aa(9)*2+aa(10) + 1; 

    if( bins(ndx) > 0)
       % Optimal row to remove was found directly.
        return;
    end
end

% Serach through all the non-empty indices that remain for best to remove.
delta      =  0;
ndx        = -1;
minSum     = sum( abs( curSum));
minSumOrig = minSum;
bestNdx    = -1;
firstFound =  1;
for ii = 1:length( bins)
    if ( bins(ii) > 0)
        tmp = sum( abs( curSum - lut( ii,:)));
        if ( firstFound) 
            minSum = tmp;
            bestNdx = ii;
            firstFound = 0;
        elseif ( tmp < minSum)
            minSum   = tmp;
            bestNdx = ii;
        end
    end
end
ndx = bestNdx;
```